# How to get details about the third party application accessing our application using Cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is there any possibility to get details about the external application that was calling our printer application to print a pdf or file.

Comment: please elaborate more... and please check how to ask questions here in Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since am new to this am facing difficulty on posting question. I will add in better way.

Comment: Here is the elaborate details. Iam creating a printer based application.by using our application we can give print directly. Any external application can call our application to print a pdf or a file. Now am searching for a Cordova plugin that need to detect which external application calling our application for printing a file.